# ARIMA cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

Using time dataset and ARIMA to predict, but always have a error

> 'cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects'

The type of dataset as below:

```
Unnamed: 0       int64
max_price      float64
mean_price     float64
min_price      float64
num_black      float64
num_blue       float64
num_disc       float64
num_grey       float64
num_nodisc     float64
num_white        int64
sale_vol         int64
size_large     float64
size_medium    float64
size_small     float64  
std_price      float64
month            int64
dtype: object
```

seems there is no str objects

```
dateparse = lambda dates:pd.datetime.strptime(dates,'%Y-%m-%d')
final = pd.read_csv('result.csv',parse_dates=['date'],index_col='date',date_parser=dateparse)
# fit model
print final.dtypes
model = ARIMA(final,order=(14,1,0))



 date         Unnamed: 0  max_price  mean_price  min_price  num_black                                                                            
2009-01-01           0  -0.724469   -0.561987  -0.153046   3.869975     
2009-02-01           1   0.196141    0.106165   0.488214   0.822881    
2009-03-01           2   0.196141    0.453011   1.242638   1.335477    
2009-04-01           3   0.196141    0.368461  -0.662282   0.794404    
2009-05-01           4   0.196141    0.224458   1.600989   1.335477
```

Comment: could you please show an example of final?

Comment: yes, I have added example of final

Comment: I think the problem might be that you are passing to `ARIMA` a 4-columns dataframe. If I use a single column it works.

Comment: No problem, little advide: as far as I know, `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX` is more supported than ARIMA, try to look into it.